# How do I resolve "too many argument..." error with php artisan serve

Tags: laravel-7

I'm on laravel 7.9.2 and wish to access my site from other systems on the LAN.

Using

```
php artisan serve --host=《my_server_ip》
```

(as advised [here](https://arunas.dev/testing-laravel-websites-over-local-network/))

I keep getting "Too many arguments, expected arguments 'command""

Answer (score 0):

Replaced '=' with space and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that "--" was replaced with "—" (long dash) maybe you have the same reason